# spring mvc resource not availble error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i am trying to test the spring mvc framework with a hello world example.I created the controller and i configured the beans and the web.xml file (you will found code bellow),but i don't know why when i did response.sendRedirect("/hello") i got
this error resource not availble.Here is my code :

My controller

```
@Controller

public class TestController {


    @RequestMapping("/hello")  
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {  

        String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC";  
        return new ModelAndView("test", "message", message);  
    }  
}
```

my spring-servlet.xml which is located under WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">
 <context:component-scan  base-package="biz.pico.ctrl" />  
 <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>testRest</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
    <display-name>spring</display-name>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>

        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the error. Please post with the complete stack trace.

Comment: Is your application deployed as the root application, or under a context path? Because redirecting to /hello redirects to /hello, not to /yourapp/hello (as the URL in the location bar should indicate).

Comment: @Alexander HTTP 404 - /hello

Comment: @JB Nizet when i did send redirect to /hello i got http://localhost:8082/hello so how can i change that to http://localhost:8082/projectName/hello

Comment: Rather than hard wiring your apps context path, you can get it from the HttpServletRequest.getContextPath().